# Another phrase for "until this time"

Tags: word-choice

I have a student (C1 level English) who has asked me for another way to say "Until this time" in an email. She wants to reference a meeting that she is having next month with an executive in another company in her complimentary close. As I don't believe my initial reaction - "um, we don't say things like that in emails in America...?" was sufficient, is there a resource that I can point her to that would provide a fairly exhaustive explanation of the rules of business email etiquette?  She said the equivalent in her L1 - Czech - is "awhile," which did not do much to help answer her question.  Stock phrases generally don't reference a specific time, obviously; which, she is aware, but wants to do something different...be original and inventive, I suppose. So what should I explain to her, and how - ?

Comment: Can you give a fuller phrase. I can see "until then" being more likely to be used than "until this time", but then again I can see "until this time" being more likely to be used than "hitherto", and really don't see anything very strange with just "until this time", though perhaps I might with more context.

Comment: What @Jon said. Without more context, the question is just too vague.

Comment: Are you looking for a phrase to use as a complimentary close, or simply a word that represents "until a certain time"? Or are you referring to the time of the meeting next month (until *that* time)? As for email etiquette, I do not believe there are any canonical references or standards. When I intend for an email to replace a written letter, I format it more or less as a letter. If it is a short comment, I format it as I would an IM. [Emily Post](http://www.emilypost.com/communication-and-technology/computers-and-communication/459-email-etiquette-dos-and-donts) has written on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

**[hitertho](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hitherto)**. Can be both an adverb and an adjective:

> *adv* **1.** until this time: `hitherto, there have been no problems.`
>
> *adj* **3.** until this time: `a hitherto unoccupied house.`

Also, **[heretofore](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heretofore)**:

> *adv.* Up to the present time; before this; previously.